# Trying to deploy an SSAS database immediately locks the user out. What is going on?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssas, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to bring a new server, with SQL Server 2012 Data Warehouse edition installed, into production.  Recently the act of deploying a new SSAS database definition using Visual Studio immediately causes the user that owns the installation on the server to become locked out of the network.  Neither I nor the network administrator can figure out what is going on.

I'm perfectly willing to believe that somewhere deep within Visual Studio it has an incorrect password for that user and is making several sequential attempts to log in until the network locks the user out.  But I have no idea where in Visual Studio that user/password is stored so that I can check it.

FWIW, I'm deploying things from a Visual Studio installation on my client computer using my personal account.  The account that is immediately getting locked is a specially created network account to be used for installing and running the server software.

Where can I find the referenced user account?  What else might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SSAs import wizard instead of using VS?